# Can I move a DOMElement while preserving focus?

Tags: javascript, dom, focus

Suppose I have a simple HTML page with a `textarea`, and I want to wrap that `textarea` in a DIV.  However, this doesn't always happen on startup / page load, so the user might have focus in that area, or even be typing.

I can move / wrap the area by creating a DIV, appending it to the `textarea`'s parent, then putting the `textarea` inside of it, and it works great.  However, when I do that, focus is removed from the `textarea` and if the user was in the middle of typing, they're going to get angry.

How can I move the `textarea`'s DOM node without interrupting the user?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the browser you may be able to determine which element has focus by using document.activeElement. Save the value before performing the move and then afterwards set the focus back using .focus() in the textarea is the same element as what you saved.

Answer (score 3):

Well, refocusing (using `focus()`) is one thing, but you'll also want to keep the user's cursor at the same location (and possibly his current selection, if he's made one). It is possible though, using the `document.selection`/`range` API, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range .

This [link](http://the-stickman.com/web-development/javascript/finding-selection-cursor-position-in-a-textarea-in-internet-explorer/) describes a solution (slightly different problem) using that API in IE.

Comment: I appreciate it, but I think this may only be in a issue in certain browsers.  Simply re-focusing on the textarea, in Firefox at least, is enough to put the cursor "back" where it was before the move.  And this is for a Greasemonkey script, so if it works in Firefox this is "good enough" for now.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to reset the focus after you move everything.

Use

```
.focus()
```

On your textArea after the move.

Comment: OK, but what if they had the focus somewhere *else* when I moved it -- I have to find out if it had focus, then re-focus it?  I mean, I wouldn't want them typing in Box A, then I move Box B and their focus jumps from A to B.

Answer (score 0):

After appending the textarea to the div you simply have to call focus on the textarea, demonstrated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/jU4pT/)

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="test">test</textarea>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('test');

setTimeout(function(){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(textarea);
    textarea.focus();
    console.log('appended');
},2000);
```